# Seach index not working when pushing new version of app

Tags: django, openshift, django-haystack, whoosh

I am using django-haystack and whoosh search engine in my django app. Everything is working alright, except when I `git push` new version to my OpenShift server, search stops working. It simply does not return any results. If I run `./manage.py update_index` it starts working.
I have `whoosh_index/` in my `.gitignore` file. I checked by `git ls-files` and whoosh_index folder is not there. So my localhost files should not be overwriting any whoosh_index files.
Currently I use `post_deploy` script:

```
echo "Executing 'python ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}wsgi/app/manage.py update_index'"
python "$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR"wsgi/app/manage.py update_index
```

**But is there another way so that I do not have to update_index everytime I push new version of my app? What am I missing?**

Comment: You update some other python files like index schema, analyzers ..?

Comment: no, even if I add only extra space in my codes(templates, ...) and push it, index will be broken.

Comment: If the index is broken so something is changed,  be sure what you push. can you show us what you got with `git show HEAD` or any breaking commit?

Comment: there are just my last edits. Nothing else. May be problem is with OpenShift - (when I commit new changes, OpenShift creates new gear, rsync all data to that and adds new data from latest commit)

Comment: so I think that's it, taking the commit as a trigger to run some routines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Modifying Applications](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-modifying-applications.html)

> All OpenShift applications are built around a Git source control workflow - you code locally, then **push your changes to the server**. The
>   server then **runs a number of hooks to build and configure your
>   application, and finally restarts your application.** Optionally,
>   applications can elect to be built using Jenkins, or run using hot
>   deployment which speeds up the deployment of code to OpenShift.

There are 5 phases for the changes done:

- Pre-Receive
- Pre-Build
- Build
- Deploy
- Post-Deploy

You can add the index update operation to the build phase by adding it to the file:

```
.openshift/action_hooks/build
```

---

You can disable the whole operation of modifying of open shift by require the hot deploy mode:

```
$ touch .openshift/markers/hot_deploy
```

> With hot deployment the changes to application code are applied
>   without restarting the application cartridge, resulting in increased
>   deployment speed and minimized application downtime.

Comment: at the moment I am using jenkins and hot deploy(I should have mentioned that, but I thought it had nothing to do with OpenShift). Only difference is that I am updating index in post_deploy. However I would like to avoid updating index, since it takes so long. I am marking your answer as accepted, since you are so helpful.